# Best way to filter results based on range slider range of values?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have a range slider that filters JavaScript objects based on their `output` key:

`<input id="outputSlider" class="form-control" type="range" min="4" max="10">`

Here's a small example of an object: (there are 50 of them)

```
const stratPickups = {
    "Model 1": {
      name: "Model 1",
      design: "single-coil",
      output: 4,
      tone: 3,
      
    },
    "Model 2": {
      name: "Model 2",
      design: "single-coil",
      output: 5,
      tone: 5,
      
    },
    "Model 3": {
      name: "Model 3",
      design: "single-coil",
      output: 6,
      tone: 6,
    },
}
```

On the input of the slider, it calls this function here:

```
const outputSliderFunction = () => {
    const slider = document.querySelector("#outputSlider");
    let sliderValue = Number(slider.value);

    activeFilters.output = sliderValue; //Pushes the slider value into an object called activeFilters

    const filteredData = performFilter(data, activeFilters);

    refreshView(filteredData); //Displays the "cards" with the product information
  };
```

Right now, this is working, but I want to improve it. The way it works now, if the `sliderValue` matches the `output`, the card gets displayed on the page. However, there are big chunks of the slider range that don't show any results. I want to change the function to accept a range of inputs, but I wasn't sure how and am looking for ideas.

I thought I could change the objects to have a `min-output` and `max-output` and figure out how to show the results when the slider value is between them, but I'm not sure how I can do that.

Any ideas?

Here's the performFilter function:

```
  const performFilter = (data, activeFilters) => {
    let result = data;
    Object.keys(activeFilters).forEach((key) => {
      result = result.filter((d) => d[key] === activeFilters[key]);
    });
    return result;
  };
```

Comment: If your `performFilter` only does `===` tests, you cannot have a `>= min` or `<= max` comparison.

Comment: So I would have to call another function that does that comparison?

Comment: Yes, or change the function.